# Converting .csv file to usable dataframe in python

Tags: python, string, csv, split, partial

I've got a .csv file that is formatted quite badly. It is just a single column with multiple time series. I would like to split the column into multiple columns based on a partial string but I am not sure where to start. The data looks like:

```
tagname1 
Time stamp:;Value:;Quality:;

2-5-2021 23:55:31;95.80;0x400c0
3-5-2021 00:06:48;95.80;0x400c0
....etc

tagname2 
Time stamp:;Value:;Quality:;

2-5-2021 23:55:31;97.80;0x400c0
3-5-2021 00:06:48;98.80;0x400c0
....etc


tagname3 
Time stamp:;Value:;Quality:;

2-5-2021 23:55:31;92.80;0x400c0
3-5-2021 00:06:48;93.80;0x400c0
....etc
```

All this data is just one single column and would like to split them up based on the tagname. The tagname always starts with the same partial string.
After splitting up this column the data needs to be split again based on the delimiter ";", but this should be relatively straightforward.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: What did you code to rectify the bad state of your csv? [mre] of you breaking it up and formatting it better? What was wrong with your code? Where is your problem?  Currently this looks like a "I need X - code it for me" task thats offtopic here.

Comment: The simplest approch probably would be to read your bad csv line-wise, create a new output file whenever you see a "tagname"  ( 'tagname_Nr{nr}.csv' ) and write all lines into that csv until you get to the next tagname. Repeat until done. That way you get to have N csv-files with time series belonging to one tag. You can then read those into N seperate dataframes that you can use as you like.

Answer (score 0):

does the .csv file has some pattern you could follow?
The best way I can think of will be to use pandas.read_csv(filepath) and then using DataFrame().iterrows to parse the file into something that makes more sense to you (perhaps if you know the number of rows between tags or even break it when "tagnamex" row appears

```
newDF = pandas.read_csv(filepath)
for row in newDF.iterrows():
    if "tagname" in row[1]:
        #start saving rows in some new array
```

after doing that you could use pandas to restructure the dataframe to your liking

Answer (score 0):

With the following csv :

```
tagname1 
Time stamp:;Value:;Quality:;

2-5-2021 23:55:31;95.80;0x400c0
3-5-2021 00:06:48;95.80;0x400c0

tagname2 
Time stamp:;Value:;Quality:;

2-5-2021 23:55:31;97.80;0x400c0
3-5-2021 00:06:48;98.80;0x400c0


tagname3 
Time stamp:;Value:;Quality:;

2-5-2021 23:55:31;92.80;0x400c0
3-5-2021 00:06:48;93.80;0x400c0
```

You can write the following code to create a dictionnary :

```
from datetime import datetime

dict_data = {}
with open('data.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

    for line in lines :
        if line.startswith('tagname'):
            tagname = line.strip()
            dict_data[tagname] = []
        else :
            try :
                int(line[0])
            except ValueError:
                pass
            except IndexError:
                pass
            else :
                dict_data[tagname].append(line.split(";"))
                #Formating
                dict_data[tagname][-1][0] = datetime.strptime(dict_data[tagname][-1][0], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
                dict_data[tagname][-1][1] = float(dict_data[tagname][-1][1])

print(dict_data['tagname1'])
# return [[datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 2, 23, 55, 31), 95.8, '0x400c0'], [datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 3, 0, 6, 48), 95.8, '0x400c0']]
```